# extract sub string using sed

Tags: regex, linux, sed

Example string is as follows:

```
KHJHGBdsg543434gdss/3_D323ABD
```

Now from the above string I want to extract letters and digits after _D (`_D` could be as reference/index) by using regular expression and sed or any other Linux command.
First: extract all the digits after `_D`, then extract the string alphabets after `_D`

Output:

```
323  
ABD
```

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Yuo can do the first part using bash parameter expansion, no need for `sed`.

Comment: Actually all can be done also with parameter expansion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the digits with

```sh
sed -e 's,.*_D,,' -e 's,[[:alpha:]],,g' <<<'KHJHGBdsg543434gdss/3_D323ABD'
323
```

and the characters with

```sh
sed -e 's,.*_D,,' -e 's,[[:digit:]],,g' <<<'KHJHGBdsg543434gdss/3_D323ABD'
ABD
```

Answer (score 1):

With sed that has the `-E`

```sh
echo 'KHJHGBdsg543434gdss/3_D323ABD' | sed -E 's/^(.+_D)([^[:alpha:]]+)(.+)$/\2 \3/'
```

With the bash shell using parameter expansion.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

raw=KHJHGBdsg543434gdss/3_D323ABD
new_raw=${raw##*_D}

int=${new_raw//[!0-9]}
str=${new_raw//[0-9]}

printf '%s\n' "$int" "$str"
```

Using the `=~` comparison operator for regex.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

[[ 'KHJHGBdsg543434gdss/3_D323ABD' =~ ^.+_D([^[:alpha:]]+)(.+)$ ]] && \ 
echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
```